difference between locating an element in two different ways in Playwright
await page.locator('nb-calendar-pageable-navigation [data-name="chevron-right]').click();
await page.locator('nb-calendar-pageable-navigation').locator('[data-name="chevron-right]').click();

I'm new to Playwright.
What is the difference between these two approaches of finding a specific element with Playwright (ts)?
Are there any preferences for using one or another?
Tried to use them for the same case, and the outcome is the same

Looking  at it from the reusability and maintenance perspective , would choose second approach :

Modularity: As a named variable it would bring modularity in the code as it can be re-used in multiple places with the combination of other locators/sub locators as well.

Ease of maintenance: if one part changes , it can be easily modified without affecting the other as may be the other part is used with other sub locators as well.

Flexibility: This way you can define lot of partial locators which can be composed together on a need basis.


I am using this way on a large scale in a project where I have thousands of partial locators which are combined in different ways in different places on need basis.

"I am using this way on a very large scale in a project where I have thousands of partial locators which are combined in different ways in different places on need basis." -- if these are CSS selectors, this sounds like a difficult to maintain project. Prefer user-visible locators: getByRole, getByPlaceholder, getByText, etc. Also, OP is just asking about whether chaining them directly on one line or not is the same. These aren't locators stored in variables, so the conversation here seems irrelevant.

The approach I mentioned using partial locators—whether they're CSS selectors or others—is focused on achieving  modularity and flexibility in a large scale project.

There is no difference. I prefer the first because it's shorter.
That said, avoid CSS selectors except as a last resort. Prefer user-visible locators like getByRole, getByPlaceholder, getByText, etc.

Keep in mind - locating purely based on text like using getByTextsometimes get unexpected results so always combine it with some other locators.

This is because same text can be at multiple places in a page.

getByText is not as ideal as getByRole, but it's almost perfectly safe if you're using strict mode and not using .first(), .last(), .nth(), so the only risk is that an element is removed and added with the same text at the same time.

Based on working on thousands of Playwright test scripts in real multiple projects , I can tell you - using getByText can really get you in trouble if you are not careful :)

@VishalAggarwal So can CSS selectors. I fail to see your points--you frequently mention that you work on big projects but you haven't presented a plausible failure scenario here or any evidence to support your claims. Simply calling things unmaintainable doesn't make them so--you need to present evidence. Here's some evidence in favor of getByText: Playwright best practices shows getByText used over and over. Again, I prefer role + text, but either one is better than CSS or XPath which you advocate for often.

Also, getByText isn't the main point of the answer. It's a totally incidental aside which you seem to be overly-focused on (as you often do on many answers). The question is about whether chaining CSS locators or using a space matters, and the answer is it doesn't really matter, but both are undesirable in testing contexts. Whether you replace it with getByText or getByRole, either one is preferred to CSS.

There is nothing wrong with using CSS/Xpath as long as you know what you are doing with it along with its strengths and limitations which is anyways true with many other things in software as well in life.

Anybody working in software engineering should not "see" things as simply black or white but should understand that there are trade-offs attached with everything. Context is the king.

There are no universal best practices , just good practices in a given context.

Then why are you attacking getByText, since there are contexts when it's useful, particularly when chained with other locators? Best practices aren't intended to be universal, they're intended to be valid most of the time, which is why they're called "best" practices, not "universal" practices. CSS and XPath aren't good in most testing contexts because they don't test user-visible functionality and are liable to break when implementation details change. I don't understand the point of this conversation.

Ok.Simple question- if you identify a UI object by unique test id using CSS/xpath , what's wrong with that?

@VishalAggarwal A lot. Test ids are not user visible behavior, it couples your test code to implementation details that engineers on another team often need to be coordinated with to change, it pollutes the code with test-only names, test id names can be misleading. It leads to testing things you shouldn't be testing, that users don't care about. Focusing on user-visible behavior (role, text, placeholder) avoids all of those problems. Test ids are generally preferred over CSS though.

@VishalAggarwal These are non-controversial, common standards beyond Playwright. RTL follows them to, and RTL is an even bigger library than Playwright (Playwright followed the user-visible trend that started post-Enzyme and post-Selenium).

Wow interesting, I never met a team in my career who wants to break their tests just because a textbox is called now "username"  instead of "user" on the screen.

@VishalAggarwal You just caught a possible typo or regression in the user-visible behavior. Tests should update when something that affects the user experience or spec (Figma design) changes, such as text changes like that. When a change breaks what the user sees and the tests don't need to change, that's the whole point of testing. Testing random implementation details like arbitrary CSS classes and test ids that don't affect users is a waste of time. This has been the standard since at least 2020 or so, back when Enzyme was on the way out and RTL and PW's philosophies were gaining traction.

Do you break your large E2E tests flows on the CI to catch spelling mistakes? Seriously!!!

@VishalAggarwal Absolutely yes, spelling mistakes are really not something I want to see in an application. It affects the user experience and makes the company look bad. It's about ensuring the app behaves exactly like the behavioral spec and Figma. Anyway, we've discussed this extensively across many threads. Suffice to say we'll need to agree to disagree, but keep in mind the community and official docs all support my philosophy, while you've provided no evidence for your perspective. Also, CI should run fast if you shard properly and don't waste time testing pointless behavior.

My point is -Large E2E test flows are not the ideal place where you catch spelling mistakes by breaking the CI pipeline.

@VishalAggarwal You talk about "breaking the CI pipeline" as if it's a sin. CI fails all the time because many PRs are not perfect on the first try. You open a PR, the tests run and fail because they've identified issues, you fix the code and push again, the tests re-run and you're good. This happens dozens of times a day for any codebase I've worked on--it's a non-event, and you want tests to fail when something is wrong in the code or a test wasn't updated. Ideally, run tests offline for faster iteration. This discussion is still largely irrelevant to my answer in any case.

@VishalAggarwal Do you ever use screenshot or snapshot tests? These tests essentially assert the exact spelling of everything on the page, as well as a bunch of other things. They're probably overly-precise, but just food for thought. Also, the spelling that E2E checks is largely incidental--the point of selecting by text isn't spell checking (although that's a side benefit), it's about avoiding selecting based on CSS. Unit tests also will select elements typically by role/text. Most apps I've worked on lately use Tailwind, so selecting by CSS is infeasible in any case.

At the end of the day, we're trying to identify a button in the most reliable manner. The current community consensus is that selecting by user-visible attributes (role, text, placeholder) is the most reliable way to select an element, avoids false positives and negatives and is maximally maintainable. Selecting by XPath, CSS and test id is discouraged because these lead to brittle, difficult to write tests that don't reflect the user experience. If you disagree, please provide evidence, because your viewpoint contradicts the established best practice.

Feel free to run Playwright's codegen, which is aligned with best practices agreed upon by the maintainers, who have tons of experience, and the community. Does it select by CSS, XPath? No, it generates getByRole mostly, with occasional filter()/getByText/getByPlaceholder, etc where appropriate.
